# Limit wrapped Text to actual text

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Row that consists of three equal parts.  The code is below and the output (screenshot) is attached

```
Row(
    children:[
      Spacer(),
      Expanded(child: Container(color:Colors.orange, child: Text("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),))),
      Spacer()
    ]
  ),
```

[image]

I would like to Center the text horizontally in the orange box (while keeping the two lines left aligned to eachother).  So I would like to move half of the space after "dog", to the left, in front of "The" and "jumps", if that makes sense.

How can I do this?  I've played with IntrinsicWidth, Center, Row, textAlign but nothing seems to work

Comment: Have you tried the center widget

Comment: Or the alignment widget

Comment: Tried both Center and Align but none of them seem to do the trick here

Comment: Can you be more specific about the 2 lines? I don't see any line

Comment: The first line is "The quick brown fox" and the second line is "jumps over the lazy dog".  I want (or the designer wants :-) ) the two lines left-aligned to eachother but the text as a whole should be centered in the orange Container

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the Text with a Padding widget with left and right padding?

Comment: @DungNgo Could be an option indeed.  However, I don't see how I could compute the required padding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to use `textWidthBasis: TextWidthBasis.longestLine`

The following code results in what I want (see screenshot)

```
Row(
    children:[
      Spacer(),
      Expanded(child: Container(
        color:Colors.orange,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Text(
                "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog",
                textWidthBasis: TextWidthBasis.longestLine,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),),
          ],
        ),
      )),
      Spacer()
    ]

  ),
```

[image]

Comment: There is still an open bounty so feel free to suggest alternative approaches!

Answer (score 0):

add `textAlign: TextAlign.center` in your text widget

Use this:

```
 Row(
children:[
  Spacer(),
  Expanded(child: Container(color:Colors.orange, child: Text("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24,),textAlign: TextAlign.center,))),
  Spacer()
]
```

),

Comment: In this case, the two lines are not aligned anymore.  I want the two lines to be left aligned to eachother but the Text-block as a whole to be centered in the orange Container

Comment: try this `textAlign: TextAlign.justify`

Comment: as expected, this adds additional spaces to the text (to justify the text on the first line left&right) so this is not my preferred solution

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please explain your answer to make it helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
Row(
    children:[
      Spacer(),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
        color: Colors.orange,
        child: Text(
          "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog",
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Spacer(),
  ],
),
```

Comment: This answer seems to be identical to the one of @aminjafari-dev, right?

Comment: @MarcVanDaele, yes, you are right.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please explain your answer to make it helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer https://stackoverflow.com/tour